# Add an event listener with sevral parameters and remove it later

Tags: javascript, event-listener

This seems to be a very popular question though i didn't seem to find any pertinat answers.

I attach an event listen like :

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', fnName, false);
```

The problem is that fnName expect several parameters, so i then triedl

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (function( e ){
   return fnName(e, some, param )
}()), false)
```

but then `window.removeEventListener` do not work anymore so i tried:

```
window.removeEventListener('scroll', (function( e ){
   return fnName(e, some, param )
}()), false)
```

Comment: Your second `addEventListener` shouldn't be working either, unless `fnName` returns a function.

Comment: It just comes down to the fact that you'll need to keep a hold on the actual handler being assigned if you want to remove it. Your last examples won't work because you're invoking the handler right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you declare an anonymous function, it creates a new function instance. If you want to remove an existing function, you need to retain a copy of the function instance.

```
var temp = function () {
    fnName(e, some, param);
};
window.addEventListener('scroll', temp, false);
//elsewhere,
window.removeEventListener('scroll', temp, false);
```

---

I should also note that using

```
(function (e){
     return fnName(e, some, param)
}());
```

calls `fnName` immediately with `undefined` as the first parameter. I doubt that's your intention.

Comment: Ok that make sense though the problem is that the event gets attached in the exposed part of an RequireJS module, so return { init : function(){... there }} and i was hoping to have the event handler declareation as a "private" method.. Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a self initializing function:

```
(function() { alert("a") })();
```

as you may a notised this code alerts `"a"`.

In your function you then initialize `fnName`. What you have to do is:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function( event ) {
   fnName(event, some, param );
}, false);
```

When the scroll event gets emitted you then init the `fnName` with your custom arguments.

---

And as pointed out if you want to remove the handler again you'ill need a named function:

```
function myFn( event ) {
   fnName(event, some, param );
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', myFn, false); // Add event listener
window.removeEventListener('scroll', myFn, false); // Remove event listener
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (function( e ){
   return fnName(e, some, param )
}), false)
```

just delete the `()` to avoid direct executing after definition

Comment: But then you have the same issue of removing the handler, which is what OP is asking about.

Comment: oh.. jepp... you also should transfer the code into another function (for example fnNameHelper) and set/remove this

Answer (score 0):

As i am in an AMD module architecture and i am trying to maintain the event handler as private method i just came up with this solution :

```
define(function(){

 var fnNmae = function( e ) {
   // i can now access fnName.param
 };

 return { 
   init : function() {
    fnName.param = {
      one : 1,
      two : 2
    }

   window.addEventListener('scroll', fnName, false);
   }

})
```